# docker node how to enable RPC?

Tags: docker

I use docker nodes. CLI is work well. but when I use this. does't work. at doc say ---  it is disabled by default.  but don't know how to enable rpc with docker node

[image]

I go to docker. find the  config.json  but 8732 or 18732 is not work. 
[image]
I use ./alphanet.sh start docker node

Answer (score 6):

At the moment the following appears to work: `alphanet.sh start --rpc-port 127.0.0.1:8732`.

Note `--rpc-port` and NOT `--rpc-addr`, this is a special case option in alphanet.sh.

This will insert a entry:

```
  ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:8732:8732"
```

into the generated docker-compose.yaml, causing the RPC to be exposed to localhost at the specified port -- it was already exposed as usual with `--rpc-addr` in the tezos-node itself, but only inside the container.

This is documented, sort of:

```
./scripts/alphanet.sh start [--rpc-port <int>] [OPTIONS]
   Launch a full Tezos alphanet node in a docker container
   automatically generating a new network identity.
   OPTIONS (others than --rpc-port) are directly passed to the
   Tezos node, see './scripts/alphanet.sh shell tezos-node config --help'
   for more details.
   By default, the RPC port is not exported outside the docker
   container. WARNING: when exported some RPCs could be harmful
   (e.g. 'inject_block', 'force_validation', ...), it is
   advised not to export them publicly.
```

Even though a port was expected (`<int>`), `--rpc-port 127.0.0.1:8732` happens to work, and should be generally safer.

Answer (score 0):

To start rpc at 8732 port use

`./alphanet.sh start --rpc-port 8732`

As mentioned in alphanet.sh script file, you can use --rpc-port option in the start command as mentioned below, specifying the port.

```
./alphanet.sh start [--rpc-port <int>] [OPTIONS]"
```

> Launch a full Tezos alphanet node in a docker container" automatically
>   generating a new network identity." OPTIONS (others than --rpc-port)
>   are directly passed to the" Tezos node, see '$0 shell tezos-node
>   config --help'" for more details." By default, the RPC port is not
>   exported outside the docker" container. WARNING: when exported some
>   RPCs could be harmful" (e.g. 'inject_block', 'force_validation', ...),
>   it is" advised not to export them publicly."

Comment: As I said in my answer, it is generally going to be safer to use `--rpc-port 127.0.0.1:8732`, when the RPC need not be accessible from any other host besides the docker host.